# How to manually generate notifications to a Google Doc collaborator?

Tags: google-docs

**Simple Use Case**:
Jane and Sue are collaboratively improvising a story in a Google Doc. Each adds at most a couple of sentences at a time and clicks an icon that notifies the other it's her turn.

**Requirements:** Ideally, the notification is apparent but unobtrusive as the collaborators may be doing other tasks in between contributions to the story. A solution that sends an email or text message is not desirable since the collaboration could generate hundreds of such messages and no one wants a more cluttered inbox. A good solution might pop up an alert or change the color of an icon in the browser.

Note also that this is not the same as notifying of a change in the file since the Google Doc AutoSave will happily save an incomplete sentence if the writer stops to think about the wording of the next phrase. The notifications need to be controlled by the writer.

I would accept a solution specific to Chrome and/or OS X but the more general the better.

**Edit:**
It looks as though using the Chrome Extensions API in conjunction with the Google Docs API is a feasible approach.  Below is a CoffeeScript pseudocode mockup of the application logic I'd like to create. As my current experience with either of these API's is limited, I'd appreciate feedback on whether the necessary capability exists in these API's. (Note: the function names in my pseudocode are not intended to match the names of any API calls. They simply identify what I want to do.)

In the code below, the term 'stickholder' refers to the idea of a Native American talking stick, a token that entitles its current holder to speak to the group. In this case, the stickholder is the id of the collaborator whose turn it is to make the next contribution.

```
$(extension_icon).on "click", clickHandler
$(extension).on "changed_doc", changeHandler

clickHandler = () ->
  adoc = getActiveBrowserPage()
  if isEditableGDoc adoc
    # Add to locally stored doc list
    # (if it's not there already)
    addToMonitoredDocList adoc
    # Check stick holder and adjust extension state.
    stickholder = getStickHolder adoc
    if isMe stickholder
      # Relinquish the stick
      setStickHolder adoc, ""
      setExtensionState adoc,  "notmyturn"
    else if stickholder == ''
      # Stick is available. Takeit.
      setStickHolder adoc, myId()
      setExtensionState adoc, "myturn"
    else
      # Stick is held by another collaborator.
      setExtensionState adoc,  "notmyturn"
  else
    # Not an editable doc, show the stickholders
    # for all the docs I'm monitoring.
    showMonitoredDocInfo()

changeHandler = (adoc) ->
  # Called when a monitored doc is changed
  stickholder = getStickHolder adoc
  if stickholder == ''
    # Another collaborator has relinquished it
    # Let me know it's available
    setExtensionState adoc, "possiblymyturn"

getActiveBrowserPage () ->
  # TODO Use Chrome Extension API to return URL
  # of active tab.
  return null

isEditableGDoc = (adoc) ->
  # TODO Use Chrome Extension API and GDocs API
  # to find out if this is a GDoc to which
  # I have editing rights. Return true or false.
  return null

addToMonitoredDocList = (adoc) ->
  # TODO Use Extension and GDoc API's tp
  # set up a change notification listener
  # for this doc and add the doc url to a locally
  # stored list for persistence.
  return null


getStickHolder = (adoc) ->
  if hasMetaDataKey adoc, "StickHolder"
    return getMetaDataValue adoc, "StickHolder"
  else
    setMetaData adoc, "StickHolder", ''
    return ''

isMe = (stickholder) ->
  return stickholder = myID()

myID = () ->
  # TODO Use Extension API to get my UserID
  return null

setExtensionState = (adoc, statestring) ->
  states = ["myturn", "notmyturn", "possiblymyturn"]
  assert statestring in states, "#{statestring} is not a valid state"
  # TODO get present state from local storage,
  # compare to new state,
  # alert me if adoc haa changed availability.
  # save new state to local storage.
  return null


hasMetaDataKey = (adoc, keystring) ->
  # TODO Use GDoc API to check existence of
  # keystring in doc's metadata (aka Properties)
  # returns true or false
  return null

getMetaDataValue = (adoc, keystring) ->
  # TODO Use GDoc API to return value of doc metadata
  # associated with keystring
  return null

showMonitoredDocInfo = () ->
  # TODO Use Storage API to fetch list of all docs being monitored.
  # For each doc, look up current stickholder and present it to me
  # as a menu or page from which I can choose to claim an available doc.
  return null

assert = (bool, msg) ->
  if not bool
    throw new Error "Assertion Failed: " + msg
```

Comment: It looks as though writing a Chrome extension might be a way to implement this.  Since that involves coding I'm wondering if I should move this question to StackOverflow.

Comment: If you're asking for a _way_ to do this, you're okay here. If you're asking for an app/tool/extension that does what you want, you're in the wrong spot. For the latter, try [softwarerecs.se]. (Some useful advice here: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3705/354)) Unless you have a specific programming problem you're having while you're building the extension, this will be off-topic at [so].

Comment: @Al E if someone knows of an extension that will solve this, that would be certainly be welcome.  So far my own searches haven't found one, so it looks like I'll need to write my own. I'm trying not to make a huge project out of this so I'm hoping someone who's already been down the road with Chrome Extensions can point me to sample code that can be adapted.